# Update view whenever document is added - Swift - Firebase Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, collections, document

I want to update the UI whenever a new document is added to a collection: this is the tricky part because using this code:

```
db.collection("Messages").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
    guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
        print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
        return
    }
    snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { diff in
        if (diff.type == .added) {
            print("New document: \(diff.document.data())")
        }
    }
}
```

I receive all of the documents of the collection firsthand. So how can I update the view depending on which document is added?

Comment: Add a listener.

Comment: already doing it, the code you see is inside the listener

Comment: We don't see it.

Comment: I updated it, now please explain what you mean with your "add a listener" statement.
I still receive all documents from the query

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some kind of framework for observing the changes? For example if you use RxSwift and you observe the document changes trough observables it is easy to update the UI in `.subscribe` part.

Comment: I'm not using any framework, just Firestore API

Comment: @StackGU what kind of view are you trying to update? Is it a tableView or CollectionView or what? We need more context.

** EDIT: 
I see the reply in other comment. You are performing a request a specific collection in your case "Messages". Do you have some kind of DTO defined for this model in the database where you parse this information? And if you don't want to receive all the documents from that collection you have to filter them. Have a look at this https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#swift

Answer (score 0):

If you are presenting a variable amount of elements then you could use `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` and if you already are and you are already receiving a collection of new data elements and you just want to show some of them then you can filter the ones you want to show, update you datasource, usually an array, and call `reloadData` on the collection view.

It shouldn't be done in a `forEach` otherwise you will have a lot of reloads, you should keep those to a minimum, therefore first `filter > assign > reload`.

You can [take look at this Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource) if helps your case.

Comment: I'm already using a collectionView, my question was more about how can I know which document is added to the firestore collection so that I can update the UI accordingly

Comment: Then I believe what you want is what I shared in the link in the answer. Diffing your collection view against the new one from Firestore with the changes will compare them and tell what has changed and update with the changes